# CMake adds Project path as prefix to RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIR

Tags: cmake

I am trying to pass a custom path (which equates to VC14 macros, i.e. $(Intdir)) to CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY prior to the cmake project call.

Through testing I have noticed anything without '/' as the first character to CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY results in the VC solution having the custom path appended to the project source dir - If '/' is the first character, the prefix is not auto-generated. How cna I provide a custom path with macros?

Comment: Please explain with examples what is the problem and what you would like to have exactly

Answer (score 1):

Those things are directly coded into CMake's Visual Studio generators. CMake does use absolute paths and if you give a relative path, it does expand it to an absolute path. See also [CMake FAQ: Why does CMake use full paths, or can I copy my build tree?](https://cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_FAQ#Why_does_CMake_use_full_paths.2C_or_can_I_copy_my_build_tree.3F)

So CMake does not recognize VS macros and - as the generated solutions are anyway not relocatable - there is normally no need for them.

You can use [generator expressions](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html) in [`CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY.html) to solve multi-configuration issues. E.g. I've tested the following with CMake 3.5.2:

```
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "$<CONFIG>")
```

For older CMake versions you would have to use [`CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_<CONFIG>`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_CONFIG.html) like

```
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_DEBUG "Debug")
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE "Release")
```